# In React Native, how do you prevent resizing in text?

Tags: string, react-native, text, view

In reference to the code below, if any of the variables within the text tag is empty the tool is smart enough to simply resize (e.g. row2, row3, row4, etc) the existing text so that there is no empty space between each line. However, I'm actually looking to retain the empty space in the event that a variable is empty.

Appreciate any input you can provide! Thank you.

```
<Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        {row2}
                        {row3}
                        {row4}
                        {row5}
                        {row6}
                        {row7}
                        {row8}
                        {row9}
                        {extraLines || undefined}
                    </Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Text>{row2 === "" ? "  " : row2}</Text>
```